# Create thumbnail in php. Image isn't saved in file

Tags: php, thumbnails

I'm trying to save images thumbnail in my php app. I have the following code but thumbnail can not be stored in file images/{image_name}.

```
$image_temp = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$image_size = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
$image_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];
$size2 = getimagesize($image_temp);
$width = $size2[0];
$height = $size2[1];    
$thumbs_destination = 'images/'.$image_name;

$newwidth = 100;
$newheight = 100;
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp);
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($thumb, $thumbs_destination);
```

I want to use my own code rather than a plugin or some code already posted in a forum so i need your help

Comment: could u add the form code here ?

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem, for example by echoing the image on the screen and checking the return value of `imagejpeg()`?

Comment: Have you made sure you have the correct permissions to write to the `images` directory?

Comment: Form code is: form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
       Choose a file to upload: <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" />
       <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
      </form>

Comment: I'm sure i have the right permissions because i also use move_uploaded_file and works fine. Variables $image_temp, $image_size, $image_name, $image_type, $size2,
$width,$height,$thumbs_destination have the values they should, I'm also trying echo $img, echo $thumb, echo imagecopyresampled() and echo imagejpeg() but nothing prints on the screen (i'm not sure if these vars should return a result).